# Unexpected behavior in MySQL causing unintended select/updates

Tags: php, mysql

In one of my projects I needed to implement some custom lock system on some rows to be processed only by one job (processor) at a time.

So I created a lock_id field in that table and I update it with the job id that's processing this row of data.

And when a new job wants to pick a free row, I will check lock_id field to be 0.

But since this project is huge, this was causing some problem when two job were trying to select a row at the same time. So I implemented a second check: when I want to update lock_id I will also check the number of affected rows, if it's zero it means another job already took this row.

`UPDATE myTable SET lock_id=1234 WHERE id=? AND lock_id=0`

**But here's the problem:**

A few days ago I encountered a weird behavior that was causing a single row getting picked by two jobs which wasn't even ran at the same time (some of them have about 30 seconds difference)!

At first I thought it might be some cache from MySQL, So I changed my SELECT Statement to this:

`SELECT myTable.*, NOW() FROM myTable WHERE lock_id=0`

But the problem is still there and I don't know what's the cause.

P.S: this project deals directly with money and every time this problem happens I'm losing real money.

PHP version: 8.1.27

MySQL version: 5.7.44

Comment: Are you using transactions? Make sure you use `FOR UPDATE` in the `SELECT` query.

Answer (score 1):

You must take into account the processes interference. I.e. you perform not "lock a row for a process" but "try to lock". And after this attempt you must ensure that the attempt is successful, and the row is reserved for current process.

I.e. you must (**step 1**):

```
-- check that there not exists the rows which are already reserved
SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE lock_id = {process ID};
```

If some value is returned then you must either process the row(s)  with returned `id` value(s) or drop the reservation (**step 2**) with

```
-- reset the row reservation
UPDATE myTable SET lock_id = 0 WHERE lock_id = {process ID};
```

If empty rowset is returned then you may reserve a row (**step 3**)

```
-- try to reserve the row
UPDATE myTable SET lock_id = {process ID} WHERE lock_id = 0 ORDER BY {something} LIMIT 1;
```

After this attempt you revert to the **step 1**.

PS. You must also save the reservation timestamp and check that there are no the rows which were reserved far ago in the event procedure. The procedure must reset the reservation for such rows. Alternatively, if you use MySQL `PROCESS_ID()`, you may check that the thread with according lock_id=processID exists, and reset the reservation for the values of non-existing threads.